# Create HTML and CSS items dynamically

Tags: html, css, jsf, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have this marketplace java web app developed using `JSF` along with `JPA` for storage. I decided to use `Zurb - Foundation 4` css front-end framework to make it look better. Unfortunately I'm still an inexperienced front-end designer. My question is: How to dynamically create items in HTML and CSS based on retrieved data from the persistence unit?

To clarify this I'll add some code regarding my current `xhtml` code and part of the `Zurb - Foundation 4` [store template](http://foundation.zurb.com/page-templates4/store.html), with which I'd like to dynamically display the results.

**xhtml:**

```
  <div id="Wrapper"> 
       <div id="content">
   <h:form>
      <h:dataTable var="_items"
                   value="#{itemManager.item}"
                   border="1"
                   binding="#{itemManager.table}">
         <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Item</f:facet>
            #{_item.name}
         </h:column>
         <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Available Units</f:facet>
            #{_item.stock}
         </h:column>
         <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Price</f:facet>
            #{_item.price}
         </h:column>
         <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Select</f:facet>
            <h:commandButton value="Select"
                             action="#{itemManager.selectItem}"/>
         </h:column>
      </h:dataTable>
   </h:form>
```

**Zurb - Foundation 4:**

```
<div class="large-8 columns">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000&text=Thumbnail">

              <div class="panel">
                <h5>Item Name</h5>
                <h6 class="subheader">$000.00</h6>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500&text=Thumbnail">
```

And so on, you know how it ends. Anyway, as you can see these "panels" are static, they are added one by one. How can they be added dynamically based on the items retrieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a standard `<h:dataTable>` if you want the generated HTML to look like this. But you can achieve something like this if you use `<ui:repeat>` which will simply iterate thought a list of items without rendering anything. This way you can render the content of the table yourself. Something like this:

```
<div class="large-8 columns">

  <ui:repeat var="_items" value="#{itemManager.item}">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
        <img src="#{_item.image}">

        <div class="panel">
          <h5>#{_item.name}</h5>
          <h6 class="subheader">#{_item.price}</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
```